# Old Version of appsettings.json is being included with compiled .NET Core App

Tags: .net-core, appsettings

My `appsettings.json` file's Build Action is `Content` and Copy to Output Directory is `Copy Always` but when building my solution, in the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` folder an old version of `appsettings.json` appears. Is there a way to ensure that an old/cached version of appsettings is not used when building a .Net Core solution?

Update: I don't know why, but I had to manually remove the `obj\Debug` folder for the newer version of the file to be used. But that seemed to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the bin folder manually, then test wether newer version are copied afterward or not.

I had similar problem after switched branches between core and full frameworks of an ASP.NET application.